# Find time in RC circut with known C and R

Tags: capacitor, resistors, remote-control

In a series RC circuit with a voltage source the Capacitance(15uF) and Resistanse(22.4ohm) is given. The time at which the Voltage across the resistor is same as the voltage across the capacitor is unknown.
How can i solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the schematic with the schematic editor that is available to you? Also, do you know how to develop the time domain equation?

Comment: @jonk I have not heard about it

Comment: School work needs to show an attempt at solving. Otherwise users will close it.

Comment: @denizyildiz70 What analysis tools are you capable of using?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the current in a DC RC-circuit is given by:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{CR}}\right)\tag1$$

So, the voltage across the resistor is given by Ohm's law:

$$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\text{R}\cdot\text{I}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{CR}}\right)\tag2$$

And the voltage across the capacitor is given by:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{CR}}\right)\right)\tag3$$

So, to find the the time when they're the same we need to solve:

$$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space t=\text{CR}\ln\left(2\right)\tag4$$